# Jquery mobile page navigation using swipe functionality in zend framework & disappearance of facebook like icons

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, zend-framework, swipe

I am developing jquery mobile web application using zend framework.Where I am using various page navigations using footer tabs and swipe functionality.

where I am facing 2 issues.

1]I am using facebook like icons in the panel of menu on each page.It disappears when i return to the page from another page link.

I have tried

1)I have including all of my js files(except jquery mobile js) after the div of page .

```
<div data-role="page" class="swipe-page type-interior" data-prev="previous_page" data-next="next_page">
```

2)http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

3)writing the script function in `$(document).on( "pageinit", function() {//function to display facebook like and send message icons. });`

```
<div  data-role="panel"  data-tap-toggle="false"
id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay"  >
<div >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 style="color:white">Menu</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-left: 18%;" class="fb-like" data-  href="https://www.facebook.com/EnablingHealthcare?ref=ts&amp;fref=ts" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="true"
    data-font="lucida grande" data-ajax="false" ></div>

</div>
</div>
```

And the js for facebook like icons is

```
 $( document ).on( "pageinit", function() {
       ( function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src =   "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=164648760363128";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));  


    });
```

2]I have added swipe functionality to every pages by providing page names in data-prev="previous_page" data-next="next_page". using the following script which is kept in separate js file and included in every page.

```
       // swipe functionality logic 
        var page = "#" + $( this ).attr( "id" ),
                next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" ),
                prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );
        if ( next ) {
            // Prefetch the next page
            $.mobile.loadPage( next  );
            // Navigate to next page on swipe left
            $( document ).on( "swipeleft", page, function() {
                $.mobile.changePage( next );
            });
        }
        if ( prev ) {
            $( document ).on( "swiperight", page, function() {
                $.mobile.changePage( prev, { reverse: true } );
            });
        }
```

In front end design it works perfectly,but
when i test my application on browser after integrating it with backend databases using zend framework. it works only for the first 3-4 times.After that it starts appending the page names in the url.Where am i doing wrong?
Please suggest for any explaination